# How to find competitive ratio of any online algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, online-algorithms, competitive-ratio

I am starting to learn online algorithms but am still stuck in determining the competitive ratio. I cannot understand how to find it. All the research papers are so difficult to understand. Please share a proper source from which I can start my journey.

Comment: While *not* a *reputable source*, [en.wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_analysis_(online_algorithm)) sheds a light on many a concept.

Comment: What paper have you read? Have you read the Sleator and Tarjan [paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/amortized-efficiency.pdf) that analyzes the MTF algorithm

Comment: I encourage you to look for textbooks, and for lecture notes from courses that cover this topic.  You should be able to find some candidates by searching on these keywords.